# Can we use node core module or other node module in React Js using bundling tool Webpack?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack-2

I try to use node core module `fs` in reactjs.

```
const fs = require('fs');
```

but it is throwing error: **"can't find module `fs`"**. can we use node core module or other module in front end side(react js) using webpack. if yes then how can we achieve this and if we can't, then is there any way to use node module in front end side ?

Answer (score 1):

Using a node module in the front end can make sense, but in the case of fs it doesn't. The file system of the client computer is not exposed to the code running on a website.

This is enforced for evident security reasons. You cannot circumvent this barrier magically using a node module on the client side.

The short answer here is : no, you can't.